# Leaving out Frozen Tilapia

Tags: fish

i took some frozen fish out the freezer Tuesday night and sat it in a sink of water, how ever my parents decided to get pizza and i thought the put it up, but it sat in the sink over night and the next day (Wednesday) it sat in the fridge till the next day. i feel bad for wasting over is so i am wondering is it still good to bake or grill or to just dump out, ive already cleaned it and 10 mins ago? i need help on this.

Comment: @sourd'oh You're right, I should have flagged instead of answering.

Comment: @logophobe That was an automatically generated reply. I don't judge, I've posted answers to questions AND flagged them for deletion before.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this thread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer) for general storage questions (edit: and [this thread](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/34670/how-do-i-know-if-food-left-at-room-temperature-is-still-safe-to-eat) for questions related to leaving food at room temperature).

Since the fish had been sitting in an open, unrefrigerated sink for what sounds like several hours, I would generally regard it as unsafe by this point.  Putting it back into the refrigerator would not sufficiently inhibit the growth of any bacteria that made their way into the fish during that time.  But there is no way to know with absolute certainty.

I'll take a cue from [rumtscho's answer](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44600/25059) to another safety-related question and note that we can't tell you here about what you *should* do.  Kitchen professionals generally err on the side of caution, but you must make your own decisions about the risk involved, and whether that outweighs any qualms you have about waste.